# Google Calendar OAuth 2.0 Error 403: access_denied

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, google-api

I have been trying to gain authorization from the Google Calendar API on my site so that I can access user calendar data. When I issue an HttpResponseRedirect from the desired view on my site via Django (to send the user to Google so they can provide the necessary permissions), the redirect works as expected. The issue is that on Google it's returning "error 403: access denied", along with a message stating that the developer must authorize my account before I can use the API (I'm trying to use a different Google account to log in for the purpose of testing). I've poked around the Google API site, but can't find where this authorization occurs. Any idea of where I might find this?
[Full Specific Error Message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvf2J.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to fix it by adding additional test users on the Google Cloud Platform (console.cloud.google.com). Navigated to the relevant project under the dropdown in the top left corner, then from there clicked the "OAuth consent screen" tab on the left hand side. You should see the option there to add users under the "Test users" header